# AppSync security best practices for 100% public, unauthenticated API's

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

We are currently deploying to AppSync using the serverless-appsync plugin and the serverless-framework (naturally).

Our API is 100% public and unauthenticated. All queries and mutations are basically public, since we have at this point no need for users (via a Cognito pool for example).

We have added a first layer of security using api keys but this is undoubtedly not much, as the api key is included as-is in the frontend sources. We would like to add extra roadblocks to make it harder for malicious users to abuse that frontend API.

A few things come to mind:

1. rate limiting (not currently supported by AppSync but I've read it's apparently in the works). I do not want to do this using a custom made solution in a Lambda for example.
2. making sure only traffic from the website is allowed to use our API, in addition to our own devs... I could probably do this with pipeline resolvers but I am not too keen with doing that in that obscure and unwieldy VTL language.
3. cors, ...

I'm considering switching to Apollo Server since this solution seems more open and configurable...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using AppSync's IAM auth option and then use [Amazon Cognito Identity Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-identity-pools.html) to vend temporary AWS credentials to your client applications. Identity pools (as opposed to user pools) vend temporary AWS credentials that assume the access of a role of your choosing. When configuring the identity pool, you can define a role with full access to the AppSync API or you may selectively provide access. From the client applications, you use the temporary credentials to sign the requests to AppSync using [SigV4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) and AppSync will only allow requests with a valid signature to be executed. The temporary credentials also provide an extra layer of security as even if they are compromised, each credential will only provide access up to the max allowed time.

I'll also add that you can use multiple auth modes at once with an AppSync API. This allows you to protect all fields as mentioned above and then selectively mark specific other fields such that they are authorized via some other mechanism like user pools or OIDC.